# "No one of" + plural noun phrase

Tags: pronouns, formality, prepositional-phrases

The [Collins English Usage](https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/no%20one)  reads

> Don't use ‘of’ after ‘*no one*’ or ‘*nobody*’; Say ‘**None** of the
> children could speak French’.

However in the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language on can find : *No one of these properties is unique*

Is this just stylistic advice? *no **single** one of*  seems to accept better plural noun phrases .

[When *none* is modified by *almost*, it is difficult to avoid treating the word as a plural: *Almost none of the officials were interviewed by the committee*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=none).

Comment: I've personally never heard the usage of "No one of [plural]," and it sounds off to me. However, "**Not** one of [plural]" sounds fine to me and I have indeed heard it before. A link to the Cambridge example would be useful.

Comment: @TylerN _**no single one of** the traditional scientific disciplines could lay a dominant claim on Allen's interests._ (Google books)

Comment: This is the [second time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541732/when-a-noun-followed-by-a-restrictive-clause-is-preceded-by-whichever-or-what) you've quoted a source and not provided the exact text. Collins *actually* says the following: "Don't use ‘of’ after ‘no one’ or ‘nobody’. ***Don't say, for example, ‘No one of the children could speak French’.*** Say ‘**None** of the children could speak."

Comment: As it stands, you have plagiarized the source by leaving out information that's essential to its original meaning.

Comment: @JasonBassford Unlike the plural _are_, the singular _Is any of the children coming?_ implies one is expected, with uncertainty as to which (American Heritage dictionary)

Comment: @JasonBassford Practical English Usage reads : _**No one** (also written no-one in British English) means the same as nobody. It cannot be followed by of: No one wished me a happy birthday, (not No one of my friends. . ._)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, but to understand why and how you need to look at the full Cambridge sentence, which, if my research is correct, is "No one of these properties is unique to adjectives, but only adjectives possess all four."

In that version of the sentence, "one" is setting up a contrast with "all four." In other words, while there is no *single one* of the properties is unique to adjectives, the set of properties taken *all together* ARE unique to adjectives.

Similarly, if the Collins sentence set up the children one by one in contrast with the children all together, "no one" would be appropriate: "No one of the the children could speak French fluently, but among them they knew enough scraps to piece together what the letter meant."

Without the second half, the Cambridge sentence "No one of these properties is unique" reads very strangely to me.

Comment: Garner's fourth edition reads _**No one of** the candidates succeeded in completely
marshaling his cohorts before the first ballot / To
the legion of the lost ones, to the cohort of the damned_

Comment: Unlike the plural _are_, the singular _Is any of the children coming?_ implies one is expected, with uncertainty as to which (American Heritage dictionary)

Comment: Yes; 'no one of ...' means 'no single-membered subset of [ξ]'. _No [single] one of these precautions will be sufficient to eradicate the virus.'_ Whereas 'not one of' means 'no member of ξ'. 'Not one of these restrictions should be relaxed.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Page 164 of Practical English Usage reads : **No one** (also written no-one in British English) means the same as nobody.
It cannot be followed by of: No one wished me a happy birthday, (not _No one of my friends. . ._)

Comment: @GJC  Grammars are not inerrant. No two of them agree completely. And no one of them is sufficient to cover all points. // 'As management expert Ken Blanchard says: “No one of us is as smart as all of us”!' [[OpenHorizons](https://ohmag.net/skypro-komnicator-1-2-no-one-of-us-is-as-smart-as-all-of-us/)]

Comment: @GJC Are you asking me a different question? Pointing me to a different ELU  'question'? Or trying to raise a counter-argument here? (Only that would be valid.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Isn't the meaning "nobody" also used in

**"No one of the the children could speak French fluently, but among them they knew enough scraps."**

Comment: I don't know what you mean. 'No one of the children ...' equates quite closely to 'No individual child present ...' here. I'd find it difficult to work 'nobody' into a paraphrase to my satisfaction. It doesn't stress 'individual/single' sufficiently.